# DOMDocument not returning correct values

Tags: php, domdocument

My document contains a bunch of divs in a document like this:

```
<div>
<h5>sometitle</h5>
<ul>
<li><a href="someurl1">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="someurl2">link2</a></li>
<li><a href="someurl2">link3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am looking to retrieve the title, and each of the href values.

I have tried something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs AS $div){
    echo $div->getElementsByTagName('h5')->nodeValue; //this doesnt work
}
```

but

```
$div->nodeValue;
```

return the title, and each of the link text. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you need to go h5's first child NodeValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), you need the first node:

```
echo $div->getElementsByTagName('h5')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Thanks that was it! Was head banging on that one. I see it now.